# UIWindow's rootViewController Property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I noticed that if I create a viewcontroller and add its view as a subview of window (a UIWindow), the display is incorrect. For some reason, my viewcontroller is displayed 40 points to the top (the same height as the status bar).

If I set the view controller to be the window's rootViewController, it displays fine.

However, if I put this viewcontroller inside a UINavigationController, I don't have to set the rootViewController property and everything works fine.

What's going on?

I need to know what UINavigationController is doing, because I'm writing a controller of controllers too, and need this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Read all of the short "Adding Content to Your Window" section in the Windows chapter of the View Programming Guide for iOS.